# Getting an error while accessing a variable that is the filename from my flask app.py in the html

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, web-applications

app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/words', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def words():
    return render_template("words.html", filename="S3.wav")
```

HTML

```
 <audio  controls="controls"  autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src='./static/'+filename  type="audio/wav">
    </audio>
```

If I am just printing it in the HTML it works using {{filename}} but it isn't accepted when added to src.

Comment: You have to use template tags. Show us what you tried with the curly brackets!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="./static/{{filename}}" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```